# Is my wifi card going bad?

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking

I've been having trouble with my wifi for a few weeks now. I have 100 mb/s from my ISP, but I only get bursts of speed every now and then. Others on my network aren't having any of the issues that I am.

I have a Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260. It's about 5 years old. I've been using `ping -n 20 8.8.8.8` to measure my packet loss which is anywhere between 10-25%. While others on the network, wired or wireless, are getting 0% packet loss.

Is this a sign that my wireless card is going bad and should be replaced?

Comment: It could be a sign that you have a loose antenna cable, or your system generates RF interference, or that your laptop is farther from the AP than the other wireless devices. Or maybe your AP has flaky 5GHz support but your laptop is the only device trying to use 5GHz. What RSSI do you get? What RSSI does a "working" device get from the same location?

Comment: It's a desktop on 2.4Ghz. The 5Ghz on my router has never worked that well so I disabled it. Connection strength is usually strong to moderate. Other devices that are near by or father away have a strong connection without this issue.

Comment: Add in that my internet connection is starting to randomly drop all together.

Comment: Have you moved either the PC or the router lately? Also, can you consider running an Ethernet cable, rather than using WiFi? Personally, I use Ethernet on my laptop where possible and on my desktop always (I have never owned a desktop PC with WiFI, nor seen the point), but YMMV.

Comment: Nope, neither have moved in about 3 years. I could try it, but I haven't had a problem with wifi in all the time, except for in the last month or so.

Comment: This might be caused by some nearby appliance, even from behind the wall.

Comment: Assuming your email tried the ubiquitous restart from complete shutdown....

Comment: This may be environmental, (a neighbor may have added a new router on your channel.) You can try moving this PC closer to the access point, or try changing the channel on the router to 1,6, or 11. If either of these work, you know it's an interference problem. Let us know the results, it's rare but wireless chipsets do indeed fail.

Comment: There are no appliances near. I'm on channel 11 because it's unpopulated in my area.